# Algorithm that spits out the smallest and largest substring starting with vowel and ending with consonant for a String

Tags: java, algorithm, lexicographic

I am trying to write such an algorithm in Java. I am testing the String input "abaab". It's safe to assume the string inputs will be lowercase.

I am at a loss in checking where my algorithm is going wrong (it only outputs "a a" for this input instead of "ab" and "abaab". Any ideas?

```
static void SmallestAndLargestSubstring(String input) {

        char[] vowels = { 'a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u' };
        char[] cons = { 'b', 'c', 'd', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'v', 'w', 'x',
                'y', 'z' };
        char[] charArray = input.toLowerCase().toCharArray();
        int startIndex = 0;
        int shortEndIndex = 0;
        int longEndIndex = 0;
        int large = longEndIndex - startIndex;
        int small = shortEndIndex - startIndex;
        ArrayList<Integer> start = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        ArrayList<Integer> end = new ArrayList<Integer>();

        outerloop: for (int i = 0; i < charArray.length; i++) {
            for (int z = 0; z < vowels.length; z++) {
                if (charArray[i] == vowels[z]) {
                    startIndex = i;
                    start.add(startIndex);
                    if (longEndIndex - startIndex > large) {
                        large = longEndIndex - startIndex;                  
                    }
                    if(longEndIndex - startIndex <= large){
                        shortEndIndex=start.get(start.size()-1);
                    }
                    if (shortEndIndex - startIndex < small) {
                        small = shortEndIndex - startIndex; 
                    }
                    if(shortEndIndex - startIndex >=small){
                        shortEndIndex=start.get(start.size()-1);
                    }


                    continue outerloop;
                }
            }
            for (int j = 0; j < cons.length; j++) {
                if (charArray[i] == cons[j]) {  
                    longEndIndex = i;
                    shortEndIndex = i;
                    end.add(longEndIndex);
                    if (longEndIndex - startIndex > large) {
                        large = longEndIndex - startIndex;
                    }if(longEndIndex - startIndex <= large){
                        longEndIndex=end.get(end.size()-1);
                    }
                    if (shortEndIndex - startIndex < small) {
                        small = shortEndIndex - startIndex;                     
                    }               
                    if(shortEndIndex - startIndex >=small) {
                        shortEndIndex=end.get(end.size()-1);
                    }
                    continue outerloop;
                }
            }
        }


        System.out.println(input.substring(startIndex, shortEndIndex));
        System.out.println(input.substring(startIndex, longEndIndex));
    }
```

Comment: You might be better off picking out all the strings, put them into a list and then figure out the smallest and largest.  Your issue is that after you find the "ab" string, you continue and it resets your indexes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is my solution : the longest substring always start with the first vowel and end with the last consonant.
For the shortest, every time I read a consonant, I look at the distance to the previous vowel and see if it is better.
You can't do anything until you read at least one vowel.

```
    static void SmallestAndLargestSubstring(String input) {

    char[] vowels = { 'a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u' };
    char[] cons = { 'b', 'c', 'd', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'v', 'w', 'x',
            'y', 'z' };
    char[] charArray = input.toLowerCase().toCharArray();
    int longStartIndex=0;
    int shortStartIndex=0;
    int shortEndIndex=0;
    int longEndIndex=0;
    boolean findVowel = false;
    int bestStart = 0;
    int bestEnd = 0;
    int shortest =Integer.MAX_VALUE;

    for (int i = 0; i < charArray.length; i++) {
        for (int z = 0; z < vowels.length; z++) {
            if (charArray[i] == vowels[z]) {
                if (!findVowel){
                    // if this is the first vowel we see
                    longStartIndex = i;
                    shortStartIndex=i;
                    findVowel = true;
                }
                else {
                     shortStartIndex = i;
                }
            }
        }
        for (int j = 0; j < cons.length; j++) {
            if (charArray[i] == cons[j]) { 
                if (findVowel){
                    // if we have seen any vowel, this consonant is useless
                    longEndIndex = i; // this one is always than the previous for the largest 
                    shortEndIndex = i; // we have to check if this one is better or not
                    if (shortEndIndex-shortStartIndex<shortest){
                         bestStart = shortStartIndex;
                         bestEnd = shortEndIndex;
                         shortest = shortEndIndex-shortStartIndex;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    System.out.println(input.substring(bestStart, bestEnd+1));
    System.out.println(input.substring(longStartIndex, longEndIndex+1));
}
```

Comment: This answer is wrong. I posted another answer, which I believe deals better with the problem.

Comment: THIS ANSWER IS WRONG - the question asks for the alphabetically largest substring rather than the longest substring

Answer (score 4):

I stumbled upon this question searching for the same problem.

> THE [CURRENTLY ACCEPTED ANSWER](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35750879/2928853) IS WRONG.

For string `uauubbiox`, the program in the accepted answer outputs:

```
ub
uauubbiox
```

which is wrong (correct answer is `auub` and `uubbiox`.) Even for the case in the OP's question, this program gives the wrong answer (`abaab` instead of `baab`).

The correct way to approach this problem is to use [suffix arrays](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Suffix_array). Here is a pseudo code that I believe will yield the correct output for this problem:

```
given string s as input
sa = suffix_array(s)
savf = the first string in sa which starts with a vowel
smallest substring = savf.substring(0, index of first consonant)

savl = the last string in sa which starts with a vowel
smallest substring = savf.substring(0, index of lastconsonant)
```

Let's try this for the test string. The suffix array for the test string is:

```
0 auubbiox
1 bbiox
2 biox
3 iox
4 ox
5 uauubbiox
6 ubbiox
7 uubbiox
```

The smallest lexicographic string starting with a vowel is:

```
auubbiox
```

We only need to find the smallest prefix in this string ending with a consonant. That will be the `b` at position 3 of the above string. Therefore, the lexicographically smallest string starting with a vowel and ending with a consonant is:

```
auub
```

For the other string, look at the largest string in suffix array starting with a vowel. That is string at index 7:

```
uubbiox
```

Since we want the largest possible string, we should chooose the longest possible prefix ending in a consonant. In this case, that will be the whole above string. Therefore the lexicographically largest string starting with a vowel and ending with a consonant is:

```
uubbiox
```

Calculating the suffix array of a string can be done in O(n). The Wikipedia article discusses some of the methods for constructing it. There are also clever techniques on the Internet that make creating one relatively easy to code and implement. I like [this one](https://web.stanford.edu/class/cs97si/suffix-array.pdf) which gives the suffix array with a very stratightforward and easy-to-understand technique with an acceptable (for most cases) time complexiy of O(nlog^2(n))

Answer (score -1):

I feel that your implementation is overly complex. There's a few things that you're trying to catch:

1) The smallest substring from a vowel to a consonant: This will be either 2 characters long or 0 characters long.

2) The longest substring from a vowel to a consonant: This will be the distance from the first vowel to the last consonant, assuming that a vowel comes before a consonant -- otherwise a length of 0.

Here is an example implementation with no substring error checking:

```
import java.util.*;

public class cons {
    public static void main(String...args)
    {
        String str = "abaab";

        char[] vowels = { 'a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u' };
        char[] cons = { 'b', 'c', 'd', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'v', 'w', 'x',
            'y', 'z' };

        int firstVowel = -1,lastConsonant = -1;
        int consVowel = -1;
        ArrayList<Character> vowel, con;

        //I use lists for the .contains() method.

        con = new ArrayList<Character>();
        vowel = new ArrayList<Character>();

        for (Character c : vowels)
            vowel.add(c);
        for (Character c : cons)
            con.add(c);

        //Algorithm starts here
        for(int i = 0; i < str.length() - 1; i++)
        {
            //position i is a vowel
            if (vowel.contains(str.charAt(i)))
            {
                //if first vowel isn't set, set it
                if (firstVowel == -1)
                    firstVowel = i;
                if (!vowel.contains(str.charAt(i+1)))
                {
                    consVowel = i;
                    lastConsonant = i+1;
                }
            } else { //Otherwise it's a consonant.
                lastConsonant = i;  //set last consonant
            }
        }

        System.out.println(str.substring(firstVowel,lastConsonant));
        System.out.println(str.substring(consVowel, consVowel+2));
    }
}
```